# How can I install another locale for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, language, locale

I've installed FF 3.6.3 on a multi-user system with the German language; however I'ld like to have everything in English (interface, etc.) for my user without installing a separate version of FF in English.

I've found the setting `general.useragent.locale` and an extension, [Quick locale switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1333/), but I don't actually understand where to get the locale from (en_US in my case, I guess).

I found pointers directing me to the official FTP release server with the hint to download the appropriate locale XPI, e.g. from http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/3.6.3/win32/en-US/ , however there's none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get language packs [from AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3).

EDIT: According to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371363), there is no en-US language pack.

Comment: English (US) is not provided, which is the one I'm searching for.

Comment: Nice, I'll accept it as it's the current status quo. I'm monitoring the Bugzilla entry and will report back once it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Language packs can be installed from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

English is probably already installed; see Tools, Addons for the list. Extensions are available to switch languages more easily than using Tools, Addons.